# message-mode for VIM? (or Composing Email in VIM)

Tags: email, vim, emacs

Emacs has something called `message-mode` (type `M-x message-mail`) that can be used to compose emails. This mode helps one to automatically wrap text to 72 columns .. keeping quoted marks properly.

Is there such a thing for VIM?

I am switching from Emacs to VIM and message-mode is the only thing that needs to be migrated.

NOTE: I don't want VIM to send emails; for that .. I use some other client. I only want to *edit* emails in VIM.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes.  Vim implements `message-mode` using filetypes.

Vim should be able to autodetect that you're editing a mail message.  It should automatically set the filetype to `mail`.  You can check this by displaying the current value of filetype by typing (in command mode) ...

```
:set filetype
```

You can also force Vim to use a particular filetype.  In command mode, type ...

```
:set filetype=mail
```

to force Vim to set the default editing preferences for mail messages.

You can read more about filetypes in the Vim help system.

```
:help filetype
```

Comment: html documentation at vim.org: http://www.vim.org/htmldoc/filetype.html (may not be up-to-date for v7.x)

Comment: But it does not automatically wrap long lines to fit the 72 cols.

Comment: What is the value of 'textwidth'? The default setting for mail is 72 which should cause your text to wrap near column 72.  Also check the value of 'warpmargin'.

Comment: I had to use `gq` to autowrap the text.

Comment: There's the following code in ftplugin/mail.vim: `if &tw == 0 ; setlocal tw=72; endif` - which should set this up properly.

Answer (score 4):

I like to run vim (vim7) as:

```
vim -c "set spell spelllang=en" -c "set tw=72" -c "set filetype=mail"
```

this turns on the built-in spell checker, line wrapping on word boundaries at 72 characters and file syntax highlighting as email.

Answer (score 0):

You want this command:

```
:set wrapmargin=8
```

Assuming that your window is set for 80 characters wide. This sets the wrap margin 8 characters from the right hand side, which gives you a width of 72.

You can abbreviate wrapmargin to wm

You may also want to check [the email category at this wiki](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Category:Email) about VIM

Comment: It makes more sense to use `:set textwidth=72` (`tw`) instead, doesn't it?